# Selecting a validation set for time-series data

Tags: time-series, validation

Question 1: How much data (how many days) should I select for validation given I have very little data to go on?

Question 2: Given that this is a textbook temporal data set situation here, how do I select validation data. I've listed my approaches below and am open to suggestions

I am trying to develop an ML based securities trading bot. Since this is a classic time-series type of problem, I have to take special care selecting my validation/training sets.
Based on some analysis it appears that the sweet spot as far as training data goes for a particular security is 65 days.

This is a bit of a specialty problem because data is naturally limited. Of course I could pull years worth of trading data, but the model drift is pretty rapid in securities ML. Since I have precious little data with only 420 minutes in main trading session, I must be very careful selecting the validation and test sets.

Here are some approaches that I am mulling and my perceived pros and cons:

1. Select last 5 days of trading for validation.

- PROS: It is a very good validation set, and it naturally points to the most recent action which is good as I am trying to predict tomorrow's action.
- CONS: This excellent data is in Val set, and NOT in training data. The most valuable (recent) training data is absent

2. Select the second-most recent 5 days (indexes -6 to -10)

- PROS: Best data gets used for training
- CONS: Validation data is not as good as in #1

3. Use days mask if index of -1 is most recent day and index of -2 is the previous day, pick validation set based on indexes [-2,-4,-5,-7,-10]
   This is sort of a compromise between 1 and 2.

For testing I use most recent days only. I feel that if I told some ML pro any one single of these methods, they would say it is acceptable.